# MySQL - Drop foreign key from many Tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to drop a Table that is referenced by many other Tables in my database. With the query below, I found 320 Tables that reference the parent Table that I want to drop.

```
SELECT
  ke.referenced_table_name parent,
  ke.table_name child,
  ke.constraint_name
FROM
  information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ke
WHERE
  ke.referenced_table_name = 'MasterData';
```

I want to drop the `FOREIGN KEY` constraints on these Tables. One by one, it would go like this:

```
ALTER TABLE a
DROP FOREIGN KEY a_md_fk;
```

Is there a way to combine these two queries, such that I drop all `FOREIGN KEY`s in one go, instead of 320 individual statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', ke.table_name, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', ke.constraint_name, ';')
FROM
  information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE ke
WHERE
  ke.referenced_table_name = 'MasterData';
```

to generate the SQL queries you need to drop the foreign keys you need.
Use your preferred way to run them (save them in a file then pipe them to the `mysql` command line client or just use copy & paste if you use a graphical MySQL client).